# How to compute a correlation matrix out of covariance matrix and mean?

Tags: correlation, covariance

[image: the task]

this is the initial info, the correlation matrix is to be computed. How could that be done?

Comment: Without worrying about matrices or vectors, do you know how one would go from covariance to correlation?

Comment: using a standard deviation.
apparently; i don't have any other data about the variables, therefore the issue with computing the deviaton from the mean

Comment: Exactly, we need a standard deviation! Do you know what the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix give you?

Comment: the covariance with the element itself. yup, got it=)

Comment: Yes, so just to be clear, the diagonal elements are the variances, so you need to take a square root to get standard deviations. But I think you got it!